# UnPivot multiple columns MSSQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a MSSQLServer table as below:

| CASNumber | ClaimVersion | ActualHSS | ApprovedHSS | ActualSurg | ApprovedSurg | ActualAmb | ApprovedAmb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GN00000068 | 1 | 819.64 | 819.64 | 190 | 120 | 1232 | 1142 |

From the above table I'm looking for an output as below:

| CASNumber | ClaimVersion | Item | Actual | Approved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GN00000068 | 1 | ActualHSS | 819.64 | 819.64 |
| GN00000068 | 1 | ActualSurg | 190 | 120 |
| GN00000068 | 1 | ActualAmb | 1232 | 1142 |

Any expertise guidance is highly appreciated.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 5):

You may unpivot the table using `VALUES` table-value constructor and an additional `APPLY` operator:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES 
   ('GN00000068', 1, 819.64, 819.64, 190, 120, 1232, 1142)
) v (CASNumber, ClaimVersion, ActualHSS, ApprovedHSS, ActualSurg, ApprovedSurg, ActualAmb, ApprovedAmb)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.CASNumber, d.ClaimVersion, v.Item, v.Actual, v.Approved
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   ('HSS', d.ActualHSS, d.ApprovedHSS),
   ('Surg', d.ActualSurg, d.ApprovedSurg),
   ('Amb', d.ActualAmb, d.ApprovedAmb)
) v (Item, Actual, Approved)
```

Result:

```
CASNumber  ClaimVersion Item  Actual  Approved
----------------------------------------------
GN00000068 1            HSS   819.64    819.64
GN00000068 1            Surg  190.00    120.00
GN00000068 1            Amb  1232.00   1142.00
```